# Prevent GPU usage in SLURM when --gpus is not set

Tags: pytorch, slurm

We're using SLURM to manage a small on-premise cluster.  A key resource we are managing is GPUs.  When a user requests GPUs via `--gpus=2` the `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` environment variable is set with the GPUs SLURM allocates to the user.

```
$ srun --gpus=2 bash -c 'echo $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES'
0,1
```

We have a small team and can trust our users to not abuse the system (they could easily overwrite the environment variable) so this works great.  However, it's a bit too easy to bypass this accidentally because when `--gpus` isn't specified `$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` is left unset so the user can use any GPU (we're typically using PyTorch).

In other words, the following command works fine (so long as it lands on a GPU node) but I would prefer that it fails (because no GPU was requested).

```
srun sudo docker run -e CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES --runtime=nvidia pytorch/pytorch:1.1.0-cuda10.0-cudnn7.5-runtime python -c 'import torch; print(torch.tensor([1., 2.], device=torch.device("cuda:0")))'
```

It would fail if `$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` were set to `-1`.

```
$ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1 sudo docker run -e CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES --runtime=nvidia pytorch/pytorch:1.1.0-cuda10.0-cudnn7.5-runtime python -c 'import torch; print(torch.tensor([1., 2.], device=torch.device("cuda:0")))'
THCudaCheck FAIL file=/opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653099582/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp line=51 error=38 : no CUDA-capable device is detected
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/torch/cuda/__init__.py", line 163, in _lazy_init
    torch._C._cuda_init()
RuntimeError: cuda runtime error (38) : no CUDA-capable device is detected at /opt/conda/conda-bld/pytorch_1556653099582/work/aten/src/THC/THCGeneral.cpp:51
```

How can I configure SLURM to set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` to `-1` when `--gpus` is not specified?

Comment: Probably, your best approach would be to have different partitions, because the modification you want to do implies tuning the code and recompile Slurm.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use the `TaskProlog` script to set the `$CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES` variable to `-1` if it was not set by Slurm.

In `slurm.conf`, configure `TaskProlog=/path/to/prolog.sh` and set the following content for `prolog.sh`.

```
#! /bin/bash

if [[ -z $CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES]]; then
echo export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1
fi
```

The `echo export ...` part will inject `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` in the job environment.

Make sure `/path/to` is visible from all compute nodes.
But this will not prevent a user from playing the system and redefining the variable from within the Python script. Really preventing access would require configuring `cgroups`.

Comment: Or, actually, you could simply set `CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=-1` in the default user profile (`/etc/profile.d`). It would then be propagate by Slurm to the job, and overwritten in case the `--gpu`  option is set.

Comment: All this untested.

Comment: thanks!  My goal isn't to build a bulletproof system but rather to guide our trusted users in the right direction.  I'll give it a try.

Comment: I tested this, this works, nvidia-smi is still visible but tasks are unable to access a GPU without overriding that env var